# How to change port for devserver

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to switch from [maven-gae-plugin](https://github.com/maven-gae-plugin/maven-gae-plugin) to [appengine-maven-plugin](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven).

So far, I was able to start devserver and everything worked fine. However, I would like know how I could change the port since I have other stuff running at 8080. Has anybody already figured this out?

Comment: maybe you want to star this issue: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/detail?id=3

Answer (score 13):

I just pushed a snapshot release that supports this option now.  You can configure it like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>8008</port>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Read http://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/ for how to get snapshot releases.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `GoogleAppEngineLauncher`, you simply click on the app and change the port there. If you are running through the terminal, use the following tags, of course you should replace `8080` with your actual port number.

```
--admin_console_server= --port=8080
```

Comment: When I run the appengine launcher and change the value, click 'Update', it doesn't change.  Even tried running as administrator

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to edit it by going to the ini file in c:/Users/me/Google/google_appengine_projects.ini

Answer (score 1):

To just run the GAE development server on a different port:

```
$ dev_appserver.py --port=<unused port> <app name>
```

(Not an answer to the exact question, but Google pointed me to this when I was searching.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the AppEngine Launcher: you can also change the port by editing the ini file directly:

```
C:/Users/username/Google/google_appengine_projects.ini
```